# Protobuf-net GetProto strange name when using List

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have the following class:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class BaseModel<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true), ]
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class IdName
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then calling the following method to generate the proto file:

```
string protoFile = Serializer.GetProto<List<IdName>>();
```

I am getting the following output:

```
package Protobuf_Test;

message BaseModel_List`1 {
   required int32 Timestamp = 1 [default = 0];
   repeated IdName Data = 2;
}
message IdName {
   optional int32 Id = 1 [default = 0];
   optional string Name = 2;
}
```

Why is generating this strange name `` BaseModel_List`1 ``?
Is there any way to set name for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question:

```
string protoFile = Serializer.GetProto<List<IdName>>();
```

works fine - no bad names. Assuming that you mean:

```
string protoFile = Serializer.GetProto<BaseModel<List<IdName>>>();
```

then that's an oversight in the generator code. [I've logged this as a bug](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/228).

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. thats what I mean.